# Breeze one-to-many deletion - children entities FKs set to 0

Tags: c#, javascript, breeze

I have been through Breeze documentation regarding navigation properties, cascade deletes and such. I have successfully managed to have one-to-many relationships work as expected with cascade deletes and Breeze. I am running out of ideas as to how the following code is failing, any help would be highly appreciated.

The code below looks similar to `Order` and `OrderDetail` classes from DocCode Breeze documentation:

```
public class Order
{
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public String Comment { get; set; }

        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrderId ")]
        [InverseProperty("OrderDetails ")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Use singular table names
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();


            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                        .HasMany(t => t.OrderDetails)
                        .WithRequired(t => t.Order)
                        .HasForeignKey(t => t.OrderId)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
}
```

When the `Order` entity is removed, I intercept the `BeforeSaveChanges` and remove all `OrderDetail` objects from the `SaveMap` as the DB will take care of deleting child entities.

**Problem**
When I create `OrderDetail` objects, these get correctly added to the DB and my Breeze client successfully manages to read these and associate them correctly. However, when I delete the `Order` object by `order.entityAspect.setDeleted();`, the children `OrderDetails` get sent to the server along with their deleted parent `Order`. The issue is that `OrderDetails` entities `OrderId` properties are set to 0. This raises a big issue as I can't identify which `OrderDetail` object to remove from the `SaveMap`

Comment: Are you sure that `[ForeignKey("OrderId ")]` attribute should mark the _Order_ property and not the _OrderId_ property? Also the spaces in _"OrderId "_ and _"OrderDetails "_ look suspicios

Comment: I think that it should be on the 'Order'. Setting it on the 'OrderId' gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server the `EntityInfo.OriginalValuesMap` will have the original values for the deleted order ids.

Comment: Thanks Jay, how can I avoid this all together? I.e Get Breeze to keep those IDs for me? Or is this the default Breeze behavior?

Comment: This is the default behavior. The idea is that when you remove the entity being pointed to by a foreign key that we should be setting the foreign key value back to its 'default' value ( usually either 0 or null). That said, we have considered making this configurable. Please post to User Voice if you think this would be useful.

Comment: I can now remove these from my `SaveMap` on the server side. How can I tell my client to forget about the `OrderDetails` that have been removed on the server (automatically removed with cascade deletes)?

Comment: You will need to do this yourself on the client either before or after the save completes.  There is also a User Voice request regarding this: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3901287-client-side-cascade-delete.  Please vote for it if you feel that its a good idea.

Comment: I just did :) Thanks a lot for your help. Will try to blog about it in case others need this.

Comment: Just as an addition: This behaviour makes it generally difficult to delete parent entities in the cache. Setting the childs to 0 in my case is a violation of the Foreign Key constraint which is not recognised by breeze. So imho it would be better to either make cascade deletes on the client work (i voted already :) or don't touch the childs at all and fire an validation error if the cache parent has cache childs.